# Does Apache Beam on Flink support start/stop with snapshots?

Tags: python, apache-flink, apache-beam

Stream processing applications run on Flink clusters using raw Flink support snapshots being taken and then the job being restarted from snapshots, by means of the Flink REST API, e.g. [stop with savepoint](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.17/docs/ops/rest_api/#jobs-jobid-stop).

Does Apache Beam using a Flink runner support start/stop with snapshots? If so, what does starting a Beam job look like? How does this change if the job is written in Python?

Answer (score -2):

Apache Beam's Flink runner does not directly support starting and stopping jobs with snapshots using the Flink REST API (e.g., stop with savepoint) like native Flink applications. The Flink runner in Apache Beam allows you to execute Apache Beam pipelines on Apache Flink, but the interaction with Flink is abstracted through the Beam API.

When starting a Beam job on the Flink runner, you typically use the standard Beam pipeline execution methods, such as pipeline.run() or submitting the job to a Beam runner, which then delegates the execution to Flink. The Beam runner handles the translation of the Beam pipeline to Flink's execution plan.

If the job is written in Java, the starting process is typically straightforward, as the Flink runner is more mature and better integrated with the Java SDK. However, if the job is written in Python, the Beam Flink runner relies on the Flink Python API for executing the pipeline, which may have certain limitations compared to the Java SDK.

Starting a Python Beam job on the Flink runner would involve the following steps:

1. Ensure you have set up the required environment, including Python, Apache Beam, and the Flink runner.
2. Write the Beam pipeline using the Python SDK.
3. Use the beam.runners.flink.FlinkRunner to submit the pipeline for execution.
4. The Flink runner will translate the Python pipeline into Flink's Python API and execute it on the Flink cluster.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, cocobot!

Both of your answers so far here appear likely to be entirely or partially written by AI (e.g., ChatGPT). A heads-up that [posting AI-generated content is not allowed here](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831). If you used an AI tool to assist with any answer, I would encourage you to delete it. 

We do hope you'll stick around and continue to be a valuable part of our community by posting *your own* quality content. Thanks!

Comment: **Readers should review this answer carefully and critically, as AI-generated information often contains fundamental errors and misinformation.** If you observe quality issues and/or have reason to believe that this answer was generated by AI, please leave feedback accordingly.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).